# Making firefox addon using Qt

Tags: qt, firefox, qt4, firefox-addon, add-on

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to make an firefox addon using Qt.If possible how can I do that ?

Comment: namely if I have made an widget using Qt now can I port it as firefox add .I will be using qt scripting..

Comment: There used to be this [Qt Netscape Plugin Extension](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.1/netscape-plugin.html) for Qt 3, to embed Qt widgets in Netscape, but I can't see a current equivalent.

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890224/embed-qt-window-into-firefox-via-plugin-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

See the Qt Browser Plugin example from Nokia/Digia/etc. Was part of Qt Solutions (now discontinued, but is under the BSD license and since it used Qt 4.x when it was supported, should still be usable, just a little dusty. Expect a bit of work to compile it at first, though).

It supports creating a NPAPI plugin. You can find the READEME at http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/blobs/master/qtbrowserplugin/README.TXT - and all the other files are in the same directory.

The documentation is also available: http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/