# Thunderbird add-on in Qt - possible?

Tags: qt, thunderbird

Is it possible to develop an add-on for Thunderbird in Qt?

I know that it is possible to develop one in C++, but the idea would be to develop the interface in Qt (using eg. QPainter), since I would like to use a library written in this framework.

- If yes, could you give some information on how to proceed or point me towards a good tutorial?
- If no, are there workarounds to achieve some kind of integration between Thunderbird and a program written in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

You can check those two questions - they are about firefix <-> qt, but if it works it should do on TB too:

- [Making firefox addon using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584858/making-firefox-addon-using-qt)
- [Embed Qt window into firefox, via plugin, on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890224/embed-qt-window-into-firefox-via-plugin-on-linux)

see also:

- http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/
- https://sites.google.com/site/qtqmlbrowserplugin/home

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately these seem to be solutions for writing a plugin. My goal would be to develop an add-on extension, like [Lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_%28software%29).